# Dynamic Paint Irrespective of Time Stretching

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups, timeline, alembic

I have this Dynamic Paint setup which influences the mapping of some droplets. As the splash happens, it wipes the droplets away based off of the merging of the two Weight Maps.

[image: WeightPaint]

The only problem is that when I go Time Stretch for rendering from 100 to 150, even if the Dynamic Paint simulation is baked with the Time Stretch of 150, the simulation/Weight Map is still off and set to the time scale of 100.

[image: Splash]

The water splash is an alembic cache that would be a huge pain to time remap to the 150 time scale, but could be a solution. Essentially duplicating the current one, time remapping it, baking that, then hiding it.

[image: MeshCache]

Any better solutions? The hidden alembic retimed to 150 feels a bit *hacky* imo. Would be cool to know why this is happening vs making weird workarounds, especially for future projects. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I too have had to use the time stretch which dynamic vertex paint and it does not seem to work.

I found a work around with the paid addon "animation layers".

1. Set the scene back to 100 time stretch.
2. Turn on animation layers on the object, then hit the + symbol, delete the extra top layer it creates if you have keyframes.
3. Go to the bottom of the animation layers - object settings and increase the sp time to match the time stretch you want. In the example pic i set it to 8 which later corresponds with a time stretching set to 800.
4. Bake the vertex paint.
5. Switch the sp back to 1.0 speed.
6. From there, you can use the time stretch in blender for the whole scene and it should all match up.

[image]